# delimit PHP/PDO execute result on multiple unrelated tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Have a PHP factory with a sub class that queries either one or more unrelated tables in a database.  The class takes a table name as a parameter and returns an array object.

When more than one table is required, I would like a way to delimit each tables result set in to its own array.  The class would then return a multi-dim array.

I would prefer to not instantiate another instance of the factory. Here is the current query/result code block. I've left out all the other non-essential code for brevity

```
// if array has more than one table to query, 
// run queries on each table
$count = count($tname);
if ($count>1) {
  foreach ($tname as $value) {          //each table name in array
    /* $query = "SELECT s.* FROM $value s"; tried with table alias */
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $value";
    if ($stmt = self::$_conn->prepare($query)) {
      $stmt->execute();
      while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $result[] = $row;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }                           
  }
  return $result;

// else if only one table to query  
} else {
  $string = $tname;                 //table name
  $query = "SELECT * FROM $string";
  if ($stmt = self::$_conn->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result[] = $row;
    }
    return $result;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

With more than one table, would return something like:

```
 Array
 ( 
   [0] => Array
    (
        [team_id] => 3
        [team_name] => Maverics
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [team_id] => 4
        [team_name] => Stallions
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [fld_id] => 1
        [fld_name] => 6v6-1
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [fld_id] => 2
        [fld_name] => 8v8-2
    )
)
```

Where 0,1 are from one table and 3,4 are from another.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... Simple actually, just didn't see it before I asked the questions. I changed:

```
 $result[] = $row;
```

to

```
 $result[$value][] = $row;   //line 11 in code block example
```

This now returns the array with each table name as the array name for the result set.
Thanks anyway,